# R take most recent observation per subject for each event

Tags: r, dplyr

**I have a data set with multiple observations of events for each subject.**

```
  DE_ID   DE_ID_VISIT     EVENT           EVENT_DATE_TIME    RESULT_VALUE
3670629183  3694982339  Height/Length, in   2020-02-06         65   
3670629183  3694982339  Weight, lbs         2020-02-06         202.8    
3670629183  3696402450  GFR Calc            2020-05-23         >60      
3670629183  3696402450  GFR Calc            2020-05-26         >60
```

**My goal is to subset the data in the format shown below where I have the most recent observation for each event for each individual subject**

```
  ID          ID_VISIT     EVENT           EVENT_DATE_TIME    RESULT_VALUE
3670629183  3694982339  Height/Length, in   2020-02-06         65   
3670629183  3694982339  Weight, lbs         2020-02-06         202.8            
3670629183  3696402450  GFR Calc            2020-05-26         >60
```

**I thought dplyr would be the easiest package to use but I am not sure how I would insert the additional grouping by EVENT**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_by(EVENT) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.Date(EVENT_DATE_TIME, '%Y/%m/%d')))
```

Answer (score 2):

When we add a new grouping, it will replace the old grouping with the new one, if we don't specify `.add = TRUE`.  Based on the code and data showed, we may need a single `group_by` with two columns 'DE_ID', 'EVENT'

```
library(dplyr) 
library(lubridate)
df %>%
      rename(ID = DE_ID) %>%
      group_by(ID, EVENT) %>%
      slice_max(ymd(EVENT_DATE_TIME)) %>%
      ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#          ID DE_ID_VISIT EVENT             EVENT_DATE_TIME RESULT_VALUE
#       <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>             <chr>           <chr>       
#1 3670629183  3696402450 GFR Calc          2020-05-26      >60         
#2 3670629183  3694982339 Height/Length, in 2020-02-06      65          
#3 3670629183  3694982339 Weight, lbs       2020-02-06      202.8
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(DE_ID = c(3670629183, 3670629183, 3670629183, 
3670629183), DE_ID_VISIT = c(3694982339, 3694982339, 3696402450, 
3696402450), EVENT = c("Height/Length, in", "Weight, lbs", "GFR Calc", 
"GFR Calc"), EVENT_DATE_TIME = c("2020-02-06", "2020-02-06", 
"2020-05-23", "2020-05-26"), RESULT_VALUE = c("65", "202.8", 
">60", ">60")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to akruns solution you can use filter:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(DE_ID, EVENT) %>%
  filter(ymd(EVENT_DATE_TIME) == max(EVENT_DATE_TIME))
```

[image]